# How to avoid copy/paste many event handlers

Tags: c#, events

My application cannot access a specific menu item unless some condition is true (DataRepository.IsAllDataLoaded). I came up with this code, which works great. It checks for the condition first. If it is not ready, it calls a timer, which waits some milliseconds and call the same method again. The Timer needs an ElapsedEventHandler.

```
public void FirstMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!DataRepository.IsAllDataLoaded)
  {
    WaitForDataLoading(FirstTimedEvent);        
  }
  else
  {        
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
   {
     IndividualEntryWindow Window = new IndividualEntryWindow();
     Window.Show();
   }));
  }
}
private void FirstTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  FirstMenuItem_Click(null, null);
}

private static void WaitForDataLoading(ElapsedEventHandler timerEvent)
{
  Timer t = new Timer();
  t.Interval = 0.2;
  t.AutoReset = false; 
  t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerEvent);
  t.Start();
}
```

Initially, the `FirstMenuItem_Click` was the only method. I had to add `FirstTimedEvent` handler for my timer. Is there a way to avoid creating that `ElapsedEventHandler`? Can I create it inline in my `FirstMenuItem_Click` method?

I now have to use that same pattern for many other Item_Click methods. I wish I don't have to create a `ElapsedEventHandler` for each Item_Click method.

Comment: Perhaps disable `FirstMenuItem` until `DataRepository.IsAllDataLoaded` is true. If you're concerned about confusion, add a little `IsBusy` indicator to whatever control `FirstMenuItem` refers to while `DataRepository.IsAllDataLoaded` remains false. Sending a process off to just spin for a static time interval while it waits for  data is a cludgey fix for this.

Comment: The goal of all this is to keep the menu enabled at all time, to give the impression that the software is ready, even if it's not. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anonymous lambda expression:

```
WaitForDataLoading((s,e) => FirstMenuItem_Click(null, null));
```

Comment: So simple. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code you can call the method `CheckDataShowWindow()` anytime you wish to show the windows when the data is ready. If you want to add it to another cick handler, you can just make another like so:

```
public void Another_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckDataShowWindow();
}
```

**Main code**:

```
public void FirstMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckDataShowWindow();
}

private void CheckDataShowWindow()
{
    if (!DataRepository.IsAllDataLoaded)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 0.2;
        t.AutoReset = false; 
        t.Elapsed += (s,e) => CheckDataShowWindow();
        t.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            IndividualEntryWindow Window = new IndividualEntryWindow();
            Window.Show();
        }));
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you can edit the code of the datarepository you should add an event for when the data is done loading.

```
public delegate void DoneLoadingHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public class DataRepository
{
    public event DoneLoadingHandler DoneLoading;
    //Your loading function
    private void LoadAllData()
    {
        //Load like you do now

        //Now fire the event that loading is done.
        if(DoneLoading != null)
            DoneLoading(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Now in your other class:

```
public void FirstMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckDataShowWindow();
}

private bool AllReadyWaiting = false;
private void CheckDataShowWindow()
{
    if (!DataRepository.IsAllDataLoaded)
    {
        if(!AllReadyWaiting)
        {
            DataRepository.DoneLoading += (s,e) => ShowWindow();
            AllReadyWaiting = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ShowWindow();
    }
}

private void ShowWindow()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        IndividualEntryWindow Window = new IndividualEntryWindow();
        Window.Show();
    }));
}
```

Comment: I suppose this answers his question about creating the timer inline with this method, but it doesn't really get to the root of the issue. Having a timer to wait for data is a crappy method of waiting for something to complete. See my comment above.

Comment: @tnw gave an answer including events.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using WPF, based on your use of the `Dispatcher` class.  That being the case, there are nicer means for you to control the access to your UI.

Two of these are:

1. bind your menu's `Enabled` property to `ViewModel` class, which would have a property to indicate whether the menu should be available.  When your long-running job is complete, set the property to `true` and the menu will be enabled.
2. use an `ICommand` to drive the behaviour of your menu.  The command's `CanExecute` return `false` while your long-running job is active, which will cause the menu to automatically be disabled until the job is complete.

It's worth noting that this will subtly change the behaviour of your menu - but not, I think, in a bad way.  Your current code will wait for the job to complete before showing the dialog - but there's nothing to stop the user clicking the menu again in the meantime.  These multiple clicks will each wait for the job to complete, and each display their own dialog when the job completes.  In a trivial case this might mean that I see multiple dialogs appear; in a severe case the multiple timers that you're creating might badly affect the performance of the application.

Either of the methods suggested above would prevent the menu from being clicked while the job is running, which is not quite your current behaviour but, I think, would make more sense from a usability perspective.

Comment: The requirement is that the menu should be enabled at all time, even if it makes the user has to wait once he clicked.